# How to convert syslog to json in syslog server on FreeBSD8.3 OS

Tags: syslog

I am using FreeBSD 8.3 and syslog server is running on it.
now i have configured my syslog server to send logs to remote server by simply adding these lines in `/etc/syslog.conf` file

```
*.notice;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;                         @10.10.1.254
news.err;local0.none;local3.none;local7.none                    @10.10.1.254
security.*                                                      @10.10.1.254
auth.info;authpriv.info;daemon.info                             @10.10.1.254
*.emerg                                                         @10.10.1.254
```

where `10.10.1.254` is my remote host IP address, it's sending the logs to remote host on `UDP`, but I want to send logs in JSON format and on `TCP`.
Is it possible?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, now what is it you are really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. That's not what syslog is for.

What I would suggest instead is to have a look at `logstash` - which is a tool for parsing syslogs and aggregating them to a database in JSON format.